# Delete Row From Colums in Android SqLite

Tags: android, sqlite, delete-row

I want to delete a single row from database , i tried different things to delete row , but database values not deleting and none of the exception is showing.I have to delete rows from two columns :

```
  public void removeSingleContact_new(String title,String titles) {
    //Open the database
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //Execute sql query to remove from database
    //NOTE: When removing by String in SQL, value must be enclosed with ''
    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_Languages + " WHERE " + KEY_SID + "= '" + title + "'" + "and" + "" + KEY + "= '" + titles + "'" );

    //Close the database
    database.close();
}
```

KEY_SID and KEY is my columns names.

DatabaseHandler.class

```
public class DataBaseHandlers extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Twilio_Configs";

// table name
private static final String TABLE_Languages = "Config_new";
values_new lang;

// Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_SID = "id";
private static final String KEY = "name";

public DataBaseHandlers(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE;

    CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_Languages + "("
            + KEY_SID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY
            + " text not null);";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Languages);
    onCreate(db);
}

void add(values_new lang) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY, lang.getValue()); // Contact Name

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_Languages, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
values_new getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_Languages, new String[] { KEY_SID,
                    KEY }, KEY_SID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) },
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    if( cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
         lang = new values_new(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1));
}return lang;}

public long getProfilesCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    long cnt  = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_Languages);
    db.close();
    return cnt;
}

// Getting All data
public List<values_new> getAllvalues() {
    List<values_new> languageList = new ArrayList<values_new>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_Languages;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            values_new lang = new values_new();
            lang.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            lang.setValue(cursor.getString(1));
            languageList.add(lang);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return languageList;
}
// Updating single record
public int update(values_new lang) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY, lang.getValue());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_Languages, values, KEY_SID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(lang.getId()) });
}
public void removeSingleContact_new(String title,String titles) {
    //Open the database
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //Execute sql query to remove from database
    //NOTE: When removing by String in SQL, value must be enclosed with ''
    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_Languages + " WHERE " + KEY_SID + "= '" + title + "'" + " AND " + "" + KEY + "= '" + titles + "'" );

    //Close the database
    database.close();
}
```

values_new:

```
public class values_new {

private long id;
private String value;

public values_new() {
    super();
}

public values_new(String value) {
    super();
    this.value = value;
}

public values_new(long id, String value) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}}
```

and using like this . :

```
 values_new singleContact_new = dbs.getContact(2);
        values_new singleContacts_news = dbs.getContact(1);

        number_sid = singleContact_new.getValue();
        twilio_number_db = singleContacts_news.getValue();
dbs.removeSingleContact_new(twilio_number_db,number_sid);
```

Please suggest me Delete command in Sqlite with and . Thankyou.

Comment: `... WHERE id= '+14132852127'andname= 'P...'` - You need a **space** between the operator `AND` and the column `Name`

Comment: If only my Errors would always be that clear...

Answer (score 5):

**Rectify your Query**

```
("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_Languages + " WHERE " + KEY_SID + "= '" + title + "'" + " AND " + "" + KEY + "= '" + titles + "'" );
```

Comment: i am removing from listview , thnax for your code it did'nt give me any exception. but not removing data from database

Comment: @SumitKumar but not removing data from database . Did you check your db ?

Comment: no , but i am checking this values_new singleContact_new = dbs.getContact(2); it gives me values.

Comment: @SumitKumar okay. after delete if you reopen activity then same problem happening ?

Comment: yes sir, it gives me same values before delete or after delete

Comment: @SumitKumar okay . for make sure,count rows no after delete

Comment: i have only one row, now i try to uninstall app and reinstall again.

Comment: i tried that when try to i delete single entry then it deletes value, but when i try to delete both, it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this:

```
public void removeSingleContact_new(String title,String titles) {

  SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

  database.delete(TABLE_Languages,
    KEY_SID + "='" + title + "' AND " + KEY + "='" + titles + "'",
    null);

  database.close();
}
```

Comment: thanx for this query, but its not delete too,

Comment: simple exception or sqllite exception?

Comment: `int count = database.delete(TABLE_Languages, KEY_SID + "='" + title + "' AND " + KEY + "='" + titles + "'", null);`. if return greater than 0 then query execute successfully otherwise not. so check return count of delete query.

Comment: Or may be there is no record in database which match with query data.

Comment: it's executing well.. otherwise it throws error... so possibility is you query data does not match with database data... so its not delete any row and return 0. pls try with another data.